# python to jython by execnet doesn't run

Tags: python, jython

I'm trying to run a example from http://codespeak.net/execnet/example/hybridpython.html but python freezes on line:

```py
gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=jython")
```

Example:

```py
import execnet
gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=jython")
channel = gw.remote_exec("""
    from java.util import Vector
    v = Vector()
    v.add('aaa')
    v.add('bbb')
    for val in v:
        channel.send(val)
""")

for item in channel:
    print (item)
```

I'm on Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation, the following is defined

```
def makegateway(self, spec=None):
    """create and configure a gateway to a Python interpreter.
    The ``spec`` string encodes the target gateway type
    and configuration information. The general format is::

        key1=value1//key2=value2//...

    If you leave out the ``=value`` part a True value is assumed.
    Valid types: ``popen``, ``ssh=hostname``, ``socket=host:port``.
    Valid configuration::

        id=<string>     specifies the gateway id
        ***python=<path>   specifies which python interpreter to execute***
        execmodel=model 'thread', 'eventlet', 'gevent' model for execution
        chdir=<path>    specifies to which directory to change
        nice=<path>     specifies process priority of new process
        env:NAME=value  specifies a remote environment variable setting.

    If no spec is given, self.defaultspec is used.
    """
```

meaning you should write:

```
gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=C:\\..\\jython2.7.0\\bin\\jython")
```

Comment: Thanks you, but i'm using linux. Path is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, the path IS necessary. It will not work without the path. It's a thing required by the libray. Here is example usage on linux, with anaconda3 `gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=/home/username/anaconda3/envs/env-name/bin/python3")`